# How to see the results in IPython Console- Spyder

Tags: ipython, spyder

I'm new to spyder and I'm trying to run the code written in the editor but the IPython console isn't showing the results like it's supposed to. All it says is run file and then the file path. I have tried resetting the spyder default settings, restarting the kernel but it doesn't work. so I wrote some code in IPython console and it does work. I don't know where to see the output of my code and I don't know what's wrong.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mzWp.png)
I'm following a tutorial and it's supposed to be like this.[Tutorial-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB6io.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The problem you're experiencing is caused because Spyder has several evaluation modes. The person in [Tutorial-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB6io.png) is selecting the code in the Editor with the mouse and then running it by pressing the <kbd>F9</kbd> key. That's why you see in that image that the code written in the editor is pasted directly into the console.

In your case case, you're running the code by pressing the `Run` button (i.e. green play button) or the <kbd>F5</kbd> key. And when do that, you need to add `print` statements to see its results in the console.

Comment: it was the same. I wasn't getting the results but now I have updated spyder and anaconda to the latest version and it works fine now

Comment: @nimramubashir, glad to know!

Answer (score 1):

you didn't output anything in your file of code. use the following code to output what you want print

```
print("hello,world!")
# or
print(a+b) # the a + b was defined in your file of code
```

**EDIT**

I installed the spyder and run the code your mentioned.

The following output is
[image]

Comment: I have tried print (a+b) and It's still the same. There is no output.